# What is __EXPORTED_HEADERS__ macro from Linux kernel used for?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have come across the following in existing macro in application makefile: `__EXPORTED_HEADERS__` added to the cflags for gcc: `CPPFLAGS+=-D__EXPORTED_HEADERS__` .

I did not find the macro itself used in the code.

I see it is used in the Linux kernel, though I dont exactly understand how it is used there.

What is it used for, and why would someone compile their code with this macro defined?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`elixir saerch __EXPORTED_HEADERS__`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/__EXPORTED_HEADERS__) -> https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/types.h#L9

There are kernel headers meant to be used from user space. And there are a lot of kernel headers meant to be used only inside the kernel.

> What is it used for,

The `__EXPORTED_HEADERS__` is used to protect against user-space source files including kernel headers not meant for user-space. In case that happens, a warning is displayed.

> why would someone compile their code with this macro defined?

To silence the warning meant for user-space when compiling as kernel.